# Помогите разобраться с простейшим классом

Tags: c++

```
//заголовочный файл example.h  
class MyExample {  
public:  
    void SetMyChr();  
    int Get_x();  
    int Get_y();

private:  
    int x[2];  
        int y[2];
```

};

```
//файл example.cpp  
#include <iostream>  
#include "example.h"

using namespace std;

void MyExample::SetMyChr() {  
    x = {534, 76};  
    y = {55, 99};  
}

int MyExample::Get_x() {  
    return x[0];  
}

int MyExample::Get_y() {  
    return y[1];  
}

int main() {  
    MyExample Test;  
    Test.SetMyChr();  
    cout << Test.Get_x() << Test.Get_y();  
    return 0;  
}
```

Что здесь не так?

C:Program FilesMicrosoft Visual StudioMyProjectsExampleexample.cpp(7) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
C:Program FilesMicrosoft Visual StudioMyProjectsExampleexample.cpp(7) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
C:Program FilesMicrosoft Visual StudioMyProjectsExampleexample.cpp(7) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
C:Program FilesMicrosoft Visual StudioMyProjectsExampleexample.cpp(8) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
C:Program FilesMicrosoft Visual StudioMyProjectsExampleexample.cpp(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
C:Program FilesMicrosoft Visual StudioMyProjectsExampleexample.cpp(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
Error executing cl.exe.

Example.exe - 6 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инициализировать массив способом

```
x = {1, 2}
```

можно только при объявлении этого массива.

Если массив уже объявлен, то инициализировать его значения только почленно :

```
int x[2];

x[0] = 2; x[1] = 5;
```

Точнее, можно так, как Вы сделали, но только в стандарте C++11, а он еще VS не поддерживается.

Т.е. функцию надо так написать

```
void MyExample::SetMyChr() {  
    x[0] = 534; x[1] = 76;  
    y[0] = 55; y[1]= 99;  
}
```

Comment: То есть как так? А если мне нужно 10000 значений проинициалировать... И, к тому же, это просто пример, я хочу разобраться... Можете привести рабочий пример?

Comment: Если очень большие массивы, то инициализировать при объявлении

int arr [100] = {4, 8, ..., 30};

Или еще лучше их писать не в тексте программы, а в отдельном файлике и во время выполнения его считывать и в цикле давать элементам массива значения.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Не понятно, за что минус "к уважению" ставят... Видимо, матерые5 "Сишники"... Куда нам смертным, начинающим?..

Answer (score 0):

для начала: SetMy**S**hr != SetMy**C**hr

Answer (score 0):

В h файле функция называется SetMy**S**hr, а в cpp MyExample::SetMy**C**hr

Comment: Все равно ошибки....

Comment: Какие ошибки? Обновите топик.